# Angular: retrieve the name of an attachment

Tags: angular, upload

I create an email sending feature with attachment on my app. I would like to retrieve the names of the attachments selected by the user in order to display them as a list. Iwould like to add a row in a table for each attachement.
I went through the angular documentation about it but I don’t succeed...

Here is the HTML to open the file dialog:

```
<div>
      <input
        type="file"
        class="file-input"
        (change)="onFileSelected($event)"
        #fileUpload
      />
      <div class="file-upload">
        <button
          mat-raised-button
          color="primary"
          class="upload-btn"
          (click)="fileUpload.click()"
        >
          <mat-icon>attach_file</mat-icon>
          {{ 'menu-partenaire.envoyerMail.boutonAjouter' | translate }}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And the .ts file, its in WIP I just try to display in the console:

```
  onFileSelected(event) {
    let input = event.target;
    let fileName = input.files[0].name;

    console.log(input, fileName);
  }
```

But the function is not called, thanks for help

**/!\EDIT/!**

the problem comes from the next css class:

```
.file-input {
  display: none;
}
```

But I have to do that otherwise the button has display problems...
The base button is displayed, with my custom button.

[image]

Comment: Your code is clean. The problem is somewhere else

Comment: I found that the problem comes from css. I've edited my post.